# Get a 10x10 numeric array from html form

Tags: php, html, json, jquery

Right now I have a php script for a battleship game that accepts a 10x10 array of single characters through json.

```
$gameId = $_POST['gameId'];       // int
$playerId = $_POST['playerId'];   //int
$boardJSON = $_POST['board'];     //10x10 json array
```

I'm trying to throw together an html/ajax form to submit this data.
What would be the best way to let a user input a 10x10 character array, serialize it, and send it as json?

This is just testing so it doesn't need to be pretty, it just needs to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have 10 strings, one for each row (makes testing easier). Just write a little Javascript to throw the data into an array.

Answer (score 0):

A 10x10 board isn't that big.  A 100-character string would do it.  Position 0 is in the upper left, and position 99 is in the lower right.  Strings are easy, right?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would just be to have an array of text elements 10x10 in a form

```
<form id='board'>
    <table>
         <?php for($y = 0; $y < 10; $y++): ?>
            <tr class="row-<?= $y ?>">
            <?php for($x = 0; $x < 10; $x++): ?>
              <td class="col-<?= $x ?>"><input type='text' size='1' maxlength='1' name="board[<?= $x ?>][<?= $y ?>]" data-x="<?= $x ?>" data-y="<?= $y ?>"/>
            <?php endfor; ?>
            </tr>
         <?php endfor; ?> 
    </table>
</form>
```

You can then use [this plugin](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/) to serialize the form to a an object.

```
var data = {};
data.gameId = gameId;
data.playerId = playerId;
data.board = $('#board').serializeObject();
```

Data can now be sent up to the server.